# Can @typescript-eslint/no-unnecessary-condition handle mutable variables?

Tags: typescript, typescript-eslint

There are a few times in our codebase where we use mutable boolean variables to control whether asynchronous tasks have been aborted mid-flight. [Here's a trivial example](https://typescript-eslint.io/play#ts=4.9.5&sourceType=module&code=IYZwngdgxgBAZgV2gFwJYHsIwCboCqgDWAFMkQFwwQIC2ARgKYBOAlDAN4CwAUDHzAHoBMACLoYIdDQYwA7uiaEeAXx48oAG1AgYBEIQBKSCMw49+MVCCMQIqCAHMYAXnjANIBmt78QydAAONnaOLjDEbM4AfGY+FnzIABZWAHRWwfZOrnDunub8qtz5fExIeoQ6rqCQsBEuMVxx8Ump6caZYcilXk0WwLLAqMg4+ETEAIwsxfGocOEAhC0gadbtjmxMDMgITBDTfQNDI+XEAExTTYWFQA&eslintrc=N4KABGBEBOCuA2BTAzpAXGYkACAXAngA4oDG0AlobgLQrzkB2uA9AwPbWwMOIkrIBDaPmok2DACblc5cekiJo0NtEgBfEGqA&tsconfig=N4KABGBEDGD2C2AHAlgGwKYCcDyiAuysAdgM6QBcYoEEkJemy0eAcgK6qoDCAFutAGsylBm3TgwAXxCSgA):

```js
async function doTask(task: number) {
 // Do some work
}

class TaskRunner {
    isRunning = false

    stopRunning = () => {
        this.isRunning = false
    }

    runTasks = async () => {
        this.isRunning = true
        await doTask(1)
        if (!this.isRunning) return // <-- Unnecessary conditional, value is always falsy.
        await doTask(2)
    }
}
```

Is there anyway of getting the rule to recognise that the boolean variable may have changed during the `await`?

Answer (score 0):

The type-aware lint rules are driven solely based on the types that TypeScript provides to it. You can see that based on intellisense TS reports the type of `this.isRunning` as `true` - which is why the lint rule reports.

[image]

Unfortunately TS does not invalidate variable refinements after an `await` or a function call - it's just a known limitation of the system which in turn flows into the lint rule.

I would personally just use an ESLint disable comment and document the reason for it, eg

```
// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-unnecessary-condition -- typescript does not invalidate the assignment refinement and thus things the type of the property is true, when it could be false
if (!this.isRunning) return
```